# facebook opengraph crawler doesn't send me fb_locale

Tags: facebook, internationalization, facebook-opengraph

I have an opengraph object that supports multiple locales (in this example, en_US by default and fr_FR).

This is an example of the generated html page that is used by the facebook opengraph but when I call it myself.

```
Default:
  <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US"/>
  <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_US" />
  <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="chair" />

?fb_locale=en_US
  <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US"/>
  <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_US" />
  <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="chair" />

?fb_locale=fr_FR
  <meta property="og:locale" content="fr_FR"/>
  <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_US" />
  <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="chaise" />
```

Facebook crawler doesn't send me neither fb_locale nor X-Facebook-Locale.

**Solution:** [Refresh the cache of facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13821478/684657)

```
curl -X POST -F "id=http://yoururl" -F "scrape=true" -F "locale=fr_fr" "https://graph.facebook.com" -s
```

(in my example, I used fr_fr)

Comment: Hi, i'm having the same problems as well. I've just opened another thread with more detailed questions concerning this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511143/how-to-implement-internationalization-of-og-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited the question, the answer is in the question.